# Como hacer que una función se repita

Tags: javascript

Como puedo hacer para que este código, se repita cada vez que cambie de  tamaño.

```
Var ancho = documento.getElementById('miid'). offsetWidth;
document.getElementById('miid2').Styles.width = ancho + "px";
```

Comment: No queda clara tu pregunta, que es lo que cambia de tamaño y a que debería afectar? Puedes colocar código ejecutable y verificable?

Comment: Cada que cambie de tamaño la pantalla o cada que pase un resize ejecute el código para que tome el nuevo valor.. nose si me explique

Comment: Un resize es un evento y es aplicado a un elemento, en este caso es sobre la ventana? o sobre un div? .. sería mejor que colocaras el código completo

Comment: Tengo dos tablas y necesito que las columnas  contengan el mismo width siempre, el .resize se ejecuta cada vez que cambia de tamaño la pantalla

Comment: Es esto que deseas: https://jsfiddle.net/fyoLnw2b/ Que ambas columnas se adapten al tamaño de la pantalla?

Comment: Hola David, anteriormente se te sugirió realizar el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos, y revisar  [ask] para formular tus preguntas.